# Ionic - Ionic cordova run android gives error?

Tags: cordova, testing, ionic-framework, build

Hi I am trying to test my ionic app in android device, the device is connected and the usb debugging mode is `ON`. when i run the command `ionic cordova run android` it does build but i get this error `cannot read property indexOf undefined`. I am attaching a screen shot for clarity.

[image]

Comment: Do `adb devices` to make sure that device is connected.

Comment: Ones you get your device in list just run `adb install PATH\TO\APK\android-debug.apk`.

Comment: I have tried like 3 devices , i get this error everytime